# How to get rid of line separator "&#13;" while serializing XML file

Tags: java, xml-serialization, eclipse-rcp, newline

I have a XML file in an XML editor (of an Eclipse RCP application) and I'd like to serialize properly the XML document, from the editor to an external location, into a file.

But, while exporting the file, I have first to remove the xmlns attribute that is present into the root element.

So that operation works fine when the document to export has a **LF** character as line separator but if it has a **CRLF** line separator, in the resulting file, I can see that the line separator has been partially encoded.

Here is a sample of a document to export (imagine that it has **CRLF** as line separator) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<document xmlns="http://mynamespace/">
    <entete>
        <rubrique>30</rubrique>
        <meta>
            <description>blablabla</description>
            <keywords>bla bla bla</keywords>
        </meta>
```

Here is the result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>&#13;
<document>&#13;
    <entete>&#13;
        <rubrique>30</rubrique>&#13;
        <meta>&#13;
            <description>blablabla</description>&#13;
            <keywords>bla bla bla</keywords>&#13;
        </meta>&#13;
```

As we can see, each line has a `&#13;` character...

Here is my code

```
IDOMModel model = (IDOMModel) targetEditor.getAdapter(IDOMModel.class);
IDOMDocument doc = model.getDocument();
FileOutputStream fos = null;
String xmlns = "";

File documentFile = new File(outputDir, fileName);
fos = new FileOutputStream(documentFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().removeAttribute("xmlns");

DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS) registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");

LSSerializer writer = impl.createLSSerializer();
writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("xml-declaration", Boolean.FALSE);

LSOutput output = impl.createLSOutput();
output.setByteStream(fos);

writer.write(model.getDocument(), output);
```

I tried many different options ...

Anybody knows how to fix that ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you serializing the file?

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? Almost all my code is here.

Comment: What is `doc`? is it holding a reference to `model.getDocument()`?

Comment: Have you tried the setting the "format-pretty-print" parameter to true? writer.getDomConfig().setParameter("format-pretty-print", Boolean.TRUE);

Comment: Ok, I've added a bit more of the code, at the beginning...

Comment: @forty-two : Yes, with or without `format-pretty-print`, the result is the same.